# SQL LOAD FILE fills table with zeros/null values

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, mariadb

So, I have an issue with loading my CSV into SQL database with PHP and Wordpress. Both are running on local xammp atm.

This is my code for loading the CSV file. It first uploads it via html form to some temp folder (data) and then tries with `LOAD DATA` to copy the content into the table (`wp_data`)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    global $wordpress,$wpdb;
    $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/data";
    $target_file = $target_dir . '/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($file, $target_file);

    $sql="
        LOAD DATA INFILE '$target_file' INTO TABLE wp_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' IGNORE 1 ROWS";
    $query = $wpdb->query($sql);
}
?>
```

The uploading part works fine, however when it tries to fill the table with the data, it just fills "0s"/NULL values, like **this**:

[image]

The file as text looks like **this**:

[image]

And visually, it looks like **this**:

[image]

Table structure from `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_data`:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_data` (
 `Unix_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Message` text NOT NULL,
 `Time` float NOT NULL,
 `DF` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Type_code/BDS_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Latitude` double NOT NULL,
 `Longitude` double NOT NULL,
 `Altitude` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Ground_speed` double NOT NULL,
 `Baro_diff` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Heading` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `TAS` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Mach` float NOT NULL,
 `FOM_SOURCE` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Wind_speed` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Wind_direction` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Temperture` text,
 `Pressure` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Turbulence` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Humidity` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am quite new at PHP and got stuck on this 
:(...

Thx.

Comment: show the table structure? `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_data` [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55407628/edit) the question with the information?

Comment: And write the file encoding here as well... pretty much looks like you have an UCS-2 encoded file and all characters are 2-byte and didn't handle it properly..

Comment: Will do. I am not sure, how to get the encoding from file, tho :-/ @LarsStegelitz

Comment: PHP has a function [mb_detect_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) which you can use if you read the uploaded file with `file_get_contents()`

Comment: notepad++ or any decent editor should be able to tell you the encoding.. otherwise, ask the source of the file (how was this file created? by whom?) :)

Comment: also to add to @LarsStegelitz comment.. PHP MySQL's Clients defaults into using `latin1`  charset.. You might need to set that also to the correct encoding with `mysqli_set_charset()` for example

Comment: Oky, it seems, that my file is in `UTF-8` and table in `latin1`, will try to change this and will let you know. Thx for help!

Comment: Use correct DATE TYPES and it may help like TIMESTAMP and DATETIME

Comment: ALso you have columns defined as NOT NULL but the data you are loading has no value for those columns

Comment: Ok, adding `CHARACTER SET UTF8` into query helped and it seems to import the data correctly now. Thank you all (also for pointing out other issues with the table)

Comment: @Václav Would be good if you delete your question or create an answer and mark it as accepted to indicate that the question has been solved and has a proper answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by setting the encoding in query to `CHARACTER SET UTF8` like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$target_file'
INTO TABLE wp_data 
CHARACTER SET UTF8 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```